# Xcode 4 "/Developer" directory is 12 GB: can it be cleaned up?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

My Developer file is 12 GB.

I am wondering if this is the normal size or could I save space? If so how?

Did I leave behing any file from older projects that  could delete?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a developer file? I don't have one! Is it good to have one?

Comment: (Seriously though, why all the down votes? If I *did* do Xcode work, I'd wonder why it was so larger ... I do VS/windows dev and my projects are *nowhere* near this large.)

Comment: @pst The OP is referring to the folder where developer tools (Xcode, frameworks, documentation, etc.) are installed. Indeed, individual projects a) are usually kept elsewhere and b) wouldn't normally be close to that size. I can't explain the downvotes, but I'd guess they might be for a poor statement of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the `/Developer` directory in the root of your hard drive?  That could have grown as a result of various installations.  Here's what I suggest: run the uninstall script, then delete the `/Developer` directory.  You'll have a clean slate.

Then download Xcode 4.3 from the Mac App Store, which actually contains all the developer files *inside* the application itself.  So you'll never need to bother with the Developer folder again.

Comment: FYI, when you run XCode4.3 for the first time, it will actually delete the /Developer folder for you (if you permit it to do so)

Comment: @JiaYow: Thanks for the heads up.  I just had a habit of erasing my developer folder before upgrades, so I guess I never got that prompt.

Comment: Oh, I see thanks. OK, just to clarify: so do I just need to upgrade to Xcode4.3 or do I still need to run the uninstall script?

Comment: @paolo: Well, according to JiaYow, Xcode 4.3 will prompt you when you first launch it saying something to the effect that it will remove the /Developer directory. I would suggest that you download Xcode 4.3, run it, and see if it prompts you, otherwise I would run the install script.

Answer (score 1):

12 GB is reasonable for your /Developer directory. Mine is 13.4 GB.

You probably don't (and shouldn't) keep your project directories in /Developer. Use /Developer for tools, libraries, etc., and use your home directory (or some other directory) for your projects. That way, you can easily back up your projects without getting all the standard developer tools, and you can upgrade or reinstall your developer tools without affecting your projects.